# How to store response from dataTaskWithUrl in other variable?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to use completion handler to store the data outside of dataTaskWithUrl to use with other methods.

This is my code :

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(true)

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
var jsonData : NSDictionary
let urlString = "<my_rest_api>"
session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: {
    (taskData, taskResponse, taskError) -> Void in
    var jsonReadError: NSError?
    var jsonResult = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(taskData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

    var resp=jsonResult["response"] as! String
    var data: NSData = resp.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    var jsonResultNested = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        jsonData = jsonResultNested[0] as! NSDictionary
    })

}).resume()
```

When I print `jsonData` outside, it says

> error: variable 'jsonData' used before being initialized

How to do this with completion handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are not initializing `jsonData`, and your `dataTaskWithURL` is async method and you can no guarantee that it will run before you access jsonData object outside completion handler.

Now there are two options either initialize it start or keep it optional and check if its not nil before accessing.

**Option 1.** Initialize it at start.

```
 var jsonData : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
```

**Option 2.** Mark is optional and check before using it if it has value

```
var jsonData : NSDictionary?
.
.
.
and where you are accessing it outside the block do this
if let dictionary = jsonData {
    // inside this access your jsonData
}
```

By doing above will remove compiler error but in both cases you will find it without any data (`empty` or `nil`) as data will be assign after `dataTaskWithURL` finished execution and call your completion handler.

Answer (score 2):

Try to read carefully and you understand problem that `jsonData` is not initialized yet.

`jsonData` is init only in async block in you're code. For solving of youre issue set default value for the property like `var jsonData = [String: String]()`

Comment: Thanks but doing this is not storing the response of `jsonResultNested[0]` in `jsonData`.

Comment: It was just example var jsonData = [String: String]() you need to init NSDictionary with proper key value types